# How to convert pyspark rdd into sparse matrix

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sparse-matrix, rdd, keyvaluepair

I have one key/value pair RDD

```
{(("a", "b"), 1), (("a", "c"), 3), (("c", "d"), 5)}
```

how could I get the sparse matrix:

```
 0  1  3  0
 1  0  0  0
 3  0  0  5
 0  0  5  0
```

i.e.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Matrices
Matrices.sparse(4, 4, [0, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2], [1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5])
```

or

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
data = [1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5]
indices = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2]
indptr = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]
csc_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(4, 4), dtype=np.float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you apply pivot to dataframe then convert to matrix?